# PHP Cookie gets removed on session end

Tags: php, session, firefox, cookies, session-cookies

Setting a cookie with the page works, but as soon as I leave the page the cookie gets removed. Browser setting is set to keep cookies and this problem doesn't happen with other websites only with this php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<title>Authentication cookie</title>
<body>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

Authentication code: <input type="text" name="authcode" value="<?php echo $_GET["authcode"]; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form><br>



<?php
$cookie_name = "authpi";
$cookie_value = $_POST["authcode"];
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/', '10.0.0.2'); // 86400 = 1 day

 ?>


<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE["authpi"])) {
     echo "Authentication Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
        #//header("Location: http://www.google.at/");
} else {
     echo "Authentication Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
     echo "Your authentication code is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>

 <p><strong>Note:</strong> After setting the Cookie reload the page to make sure it works!</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Why is the cookie removed after leaving the page?

PS: creating the cookie isn't the problem. That works fine.

Comment: How do you check for the presence of the cookie after the browser leaves the page?  And do you mean leave to go to another domain, or leave the page but stays on your domain?

Comment: Going to another domain and visiting the page again says that the cookie doesn't exist.
Leaving the page and going to another page on the same domain, going back then says also that the cookie doesn't exist

Comment: Sounds like issue 1 in my post.  You said creating the cookie isn't the problem. How have you established that the cookie is properly set to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

The cookie is never set.

You are trying to set a cookie after headers have been sent. If you want to do that, you need to use output buffers, meaning you have to use `ob_start();` before you send any headers to the browser.

More about `ob_start();`: [Output Buffers PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Easy note: That code.. is a mess.

Working example of your code (still messy because it was a fast coding)

```
<?php

    $cookie_name = "authpi";

    if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
        $cookie_value = $_POST["authcode"];
        $domain = ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost') ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : false;

        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 60), '/', $domain); // 86400 = 1 day
    }
    if(!isset($_COOKIE["authpi"])) {
        echo "Authentication Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
    } else {
        echo "Authentication Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
        echo "Your authentication code is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
    }


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Authentication cookie</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">

            Authentication code: <input type="text" name="authcode" value="<?php echo $_GET["authcode"]; ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <br>

        <p><strong>Note:</strong> After setting the Cookie reload the page to make sure it works!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but I don't think doing it this (your) way will set the users form input as cookie value?

Comment: PS: I know my code is really messy but this is just a little workaround for a home automation system so that not anyone on the network can controll stuff.

Comment: @cr78 Yes it does set the cookie as the value the user inputs. The page sets `POST` data after the form is submitted, and redirects it to `action` which is itself. then, the `POST` data is used.

Comment: You say that the cookie is never set. If type stuff in the html form on the page and press submit the cookie is set. if i reload the page the cookie also gets recognised by the php code and it echos out that it found the cookie. The cookie is also existing in the browser (firefox delete cookie menu shows the cookie). 

The problem is the following: If i leave the page which sets the cookie, the cookie gets deleted from the browser. Like the end of a session but cookies from all other websites don't show this problem.

Comment: @cr78 I don't mean to be disrespectful! You need to read more information about form submissions and headers. It is impossible for your cookie to be set without activating `output buffering`. Also, the value the user types in the input, gets to be used ONLY after the form is submitted and redirected to the `action` destination. At te `action` destination you retrieve the data securely with `$_POST` but in most cases you can do it with `$_GET` even if it's not recommended.

Comment: @cr78 The fact that you somehow set a cookie by the form submission must have something to do with other scripts you use on the same server/domain/path. By this script only, it is simply impossible.

Comment: I also don't mean to be disrespectful but there are no other scripts on the server which set cookies. After pressing the submit button the user has to reload the page to set the cookie, but then it exists as long as the user is on the page

Comment: @cr78 It just makes no sense. The cookie in your example. will. never. be. set.  
Reason: [HTTP Protocol regarding cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

Comment: Also do you mean I could get that working so that if the user types in his authcode and the submit button is pressed that a cookie is set (with or without reloading the page after submitting) So that I can read out the cookie value on the main site of the home automation?

Or should i think of another way of authentication?

Comment: @cr78 I do not know what you are trying to accomplish and your english is not helping me too much to understand. I tend to believe you try to code something that is beyond your knowledge, try studying before throwing yourself to bigger projects. If you are trying to develop a login system, then you should have a look into `sessions`, `databases` and `mysqli` or `pdo`

Comment: about this specific question, both mine and @BeetleJuice s answers are correct.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time and answers. Looks like i have to study way more to accomplish something like that authentication system. Have a nice day!

Comment: Good starting point would be taking my code and editing it according to your needs until you succeed. Or following @BeetleJuice 's start-up.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `setcookie()` or any other function that change http headers after you've already sent content to the browser.  There cannot be *anything* (not even blank space) before the opening `<?php` of the code block that includes these functions (unless you enabled output buffering).

Move your cookie setting before `<!DOCTYPE html>`

If you only want to set your cookie after the user submits the authentication code on the form, the correct code (still goes before all HTML) looks like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'],$_POST['authcode'])){
    //set your cookie here
}
```

From [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your
>   script. This requires that you place
>   calls to this function prior to any output, including  and
>    tags as well as any whitespace.

Comment: 1. If I would set the cookie at the beginning of the code, before the user has typed in the auth-code the whole thing would lose its purpose because the authcode typed in by the user is the important thing on this. Setting the cookie still works fine with the mentioned code.

2. The authcode doesn't come from the url, it comes from the html form where the user types it in.

3. All that doesn't solve the problem! The problem is that the cookie dissappears in firefox after leaving the page, although the cookie lifetime is long enough.

Comment: @cr78 you're mistaken about the timing of cookie setting events. If your cookie is being set successfully, it is still being set before the user even sees the form, no matter where `setcookie()` is in the code. As I wrote, this is a headers-setting function which means it *always* happens before the browser even downloads the page.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I think i understand... So you mean the cookie is set at (or before) page loading and the value gets changed after the user typed in the wanted value in the form?

Comment: @cr78 Fundamentally, PHP code execution and html/javascript execution never overlap. All PHP happens before the browser gets involved. `setcookie` asks the browser, when it eventually downloads the page, to set a cookie. The cookie setting itself is done after the page has left the server, so PHP cannot dynamically change this value based on user input. What happens is that on the next http request (page reload, form submit etc...), PHP can see the user's input and ask the browser, when it later receives the response from the server, to set the cookie to a different value.